# How to convert fs:path to variable

Tags: c++, path, fs

Ok, firstly, I'm new to this. So yell at me as much as you like, but try to be useful at the same time :)

So I'm attempting to build a plugin using C++ to find a log file, and upload to a FTP every few minutes. The idea is to allow administrators to see the logs without needing direct access to the server. The ftp was the easy bit of this, running `#include <CkFtp2.h>` to do most of this with ease. I then used fs::path to find the latest file edited. Which looked like this:

```
//finding the latest file

int FindFile() {
    fs::path latest;
    std::time_t latest_tm {};

    for (auto&& entry : boost::make_iterator_range(fs::directory_iterator("."), {})) {
        fs::path p = entry.path();
        if (is_regular_file(p) && p.extension() == ".txt") 
        {
            std::time_t timestamp = fs::last_write_time(p);
            if (timestamp > latest_tm) {
                latest = p;
                latest_tm = timestamp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now want to define `string localFilename = latest` however I get `error: no viable conversion from 'fs::path' to 'string`. Could someone help me?

Check out my github here to see what I'm working on and how I want this to implement with the rest of the code: https://github.com/TGTGamer/sourcebansLogMonitoring/blob/master/SourcebansToFTP.sp

p.s. If i'm being stupid, tell me the answer then slap me round the face....

Comment: A `char` is a single character. Maybe you want `std::string`?

Comment: Why not simply `fs::path localFilename = latest;` or if you want to obtain a string from the path: `auto str = latest.native()`. Method `native()` may return either `std::string` or `std::wstring` depending on platform.

Comment: @zett42, I want latest to be called later in the file, as can be seen on my github. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @Galik for pointing out that stupid mistake, but I have updated that on my github... xD

Comment: Did you try `std::string` or just `string`?

Comment: @Galik, I tried both `string` (Error unknown name type) and `std::string` (Error: no viable conversion). I also run @zett42 solution which works. Proving i was just being stupid.... xD